# Operation based HTTP interface Richardson Maturity Model Level REST

Tags: rest

If a service includes URL's for different operations (verbs not nouns):

e.g.

```
Http://aaa.com/api/clients/UpdateClient
http://aaa.com/api/clients/RemoveClient
http://aaa.com/api/messaging/SendMessage
```

Would this be classified as RMM level 0?

Based on examples

```
http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html
```

It does not seem to match even Level 0

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Richardson Maturity Model is based on REST, and the urls you provide are not RESTful, they don't classify as any one of the 4 levels.

It is not RESTful to put a verb in an url.  (see http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html)

The HTTP verbs that are mentioned in the link you posted are PUT, POST, GET, etc. HTTP verbs are not related to the actual url they operate on.

A RESTful version of `http://aaa.com/api/clients/UpdateClient` would be

```
http://aaa.com/api/clients/:client_id
```

UpdateClient would translate to

```
PUT http://aaa.com/api/clients/1 HTTP/1.1
```

Where a new (updated) resource is provided, to replace an existing one (client 1 in this case)

RemoveClient would translate to

```
DELETE http://aaa.com/api/clients/1 HTTP/1.1
```

DELETE and PUT as shown here are the HTTP verbs that are discussed in the link you provide.

Comment: I understand this.  To me it seems RMM Level 0 and 1 are not RESTful.  Would you consider these levels RESTful?

Comment: I don't think 0 is very RESTful, because `/appointmentService` doesn't look like a RESTful url. It's appointments that a user interacts with, not appointmentServices. 1 however does look RESTul. `/doctors/mjones` is a fine RESTful url. `/doctors` refers to all doctors, and `/mjones` refers to 1 specific doctor named mjones

Comment: "level 3 RMM is a pre-condition of REST" from the Martin Fowler article linked in the question